# Как переименовать окно консоли в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

Есть исполняемый скрипт (в моем случае "автологин"), как можно реализовать переименование окна терминала в котором он запущен?

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается все просто:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("\x1b]0;test\x07") #Zagolovok test
```

Comment: Это не будет работать под Windows. Добавьте в вопрос метку системы.